# Postgres Given error "failed to initialize transaction_deferrable to 0"

Tags: postgresql

I have installed postgres 11 and i am using "SET TRANSACTION NOT DEFERRABLE". But postgres given error "failed to initialize transaction_deferrable to 0". i just need to know about this error means what is meaning of this error.

Comment: That is an internal error that should only occur during backend start, if I read the code right. Do you get the error right when you do the `SET` or later? Is parallel query involved? Please give us more details, for example how to reproduce it. This might be a PostgreSQL bug. Do you have any extensions installed?

Comment: Ok, parallel worker, as I thought it might be. Can you come up with a reproducible test case? Do you have the latest minor version of PostgreSQL v11? You should report this as a PostgreSQL bug, but with some more information.

Comment: I have used parallel query execution and this error is occurred when data is big. When data is small then it works fine.

Comment: With postgres 9, my code is working fine. i have migrated postgres 9 to 11.

Comment: Please address my comments, so that this problem can be resolved.